# System very Slow, Trying to find the bottleneck

Tags: 12.10, performance, disk

I have Ubuntu 12.10 installed in Sony VIAO E Series VPCEH16EN, 4GB RAM, 320 GB HDD, Intel Core i3-2310M Processor 2.10GHz. It is a dual boot with Windows7 alongside with it.

I see the system is very slow in responding, any video gets stuck in between the play. Can you please help me find where the bottleneck is. Here is the output of `hdparm` and `smartctl`:

```
------------- HDPARM -------------------
anil@anil-ubuntu:~$ sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sda6 
/dev/sda6:
 Timing cached reads:     2 MB in  3.51 seconds = 584.17 kB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 160 MB in  3.02 seconds =  52.91 MB/sec
anil@anil-ubuntu:~$ 
-----------------------------------------

-------------- SMARTCTL -----------------
anil@anil-ubuntu:~$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda6
smartctl 5.43 2012-06-30 r3573 [x86_64-linux-3.5.0-25-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-12 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MK3265GSXN
Serial Number:    419CD3X3B
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 33ab02a3c
Firmware Version: GH012H
User Capacity:    320,072,933,376 bytes [320 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  Exact ATA specification draft version not indicated
Local Time is:    Thu Feb 28 23:08:07 2013 IST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  95) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       1258
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2560
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       47
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   088   088   000    Old_age   Always       -       4940
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   150   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2553
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       118
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       169
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       13993
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       43 (Min/Max 20/47)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       5
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
220 Disk_Shift              0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       19
222 Loaded_Hours            0x0032   091   091   000    Old_age   Always       -       3918
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
224 Load_Friction           0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
226 Load-in_Time            0x0026   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       245
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0001   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 108 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.
Error 108 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 3337 hours (139 days + 1 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.
  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 4a 6a 9d bb 64  Error: WP at LBA = 0x04bb9d6a = 79404394
  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 08 58 f0 f6 b8 40 00      03:49:54.536  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 50 00 f7 b8 40 00      03:49:54.536  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 48 98 9c bb 40 00      03:49:54.535  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 38 40 c8 0b b9 40 00      03:49:54.535  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 02 38 88 3a 39 40 00      03:49:54.535  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Error 107 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 3337 hours (139 days + 1 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.
  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 f2 6a 9d bb 64  Error: WP at LBA = 0x04bb9d6a = 79404394
  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 08 f8 68 c9 65 40 00      03:49:50.336  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 f0 98 9c bb 40 00      03:49:50.335  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 e8 28 71 61 40 00      03:49:50.335  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 18 e0 08 c8 61 40 00      03:49:50.335  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 20 d8 d8 90 6c 40 00      03:49:50.335  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Error 106 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 3337 hours (139 days + 1 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.
  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 62 6a 9d bb 64  Error: WP at LBA = 0x04bb9d6a = 79404394
  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 08 70 f8 f6 b8 40 00      03:49:46.159  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 68 08 f7 b8 40 00      03:49:46.159  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 60 98 9c bb 40 00      03:49:46.157  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 58 c0 0b b9 40 00      03:49:46.157  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 50 e8 38 62 40 00      03:49:46.157  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Error 105 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 3337 hours (139 days + 1 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.
  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 aa 6a 9d bb 64  Error: WP at LBA = 0x04bb9d6a = 79404394
  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 08 00 28 87 7e 40 00      03:49:41.973  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 f8 78 7d 7e 40 00      03:49:41.972  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 f0 40 7d 7e 40 00      03:49:41.972  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 e8 88 72 7e 40 00      03:49:41.972  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 e0 d0 5e 7e 40 00      03:49:41.972  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Error 104 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 3337 hours (139 days + 1 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.
  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 52 6a 9d bb 64  Error: WP at LBA = 0x04bb9d6a = 79404394
  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 08 78 f0 04 bd 40 00      03:49:37.805  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 70 20 03 bd 40 00      03:49:37.804  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 68 08 03 bd 40 00      03:49:37.804  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 10 60 e8 02 bd 40 00      03:49:37.803  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 03 58 d8 f2 6f 40 00      03:49:37.803  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]
SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Am I the only one that thinks 584.17 kB/sec for cached reads is so slow!

Answer (score 1):

Your S.M.A.R.T. data from your disk shows that your hard drive is failing. I would backup any information you might have important in your disk and replace it asap.

All the **Type:** *Pre-fail* warnings should be clear of that with addition to the [104, 105, 106, 107 and 108](http://support.wdc.com/techinfo/general/errorcodes.asp) errors in the `smartctl` report.

You can also check the status of your hard disk conditions (show by the S.M.A.R.T. data) by using the `palimpsest` (`Disk Utility`) and checking the status there

[image]